# PHP отправить PUT запрос

Tags: php

Как через `PHP CURL` отправить данный запрос `PUT`.

```
PUT /api/tickets/{id}

{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "Help me!",
  "group": "Users",
  "state": "open",
  "priority": "3 high",
  "article": {
    "subject": "some subject of update",
    "body": "some message of update"
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44918152/curlopt-put-vs-curlopt-postfields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Советую Вам более детально изучить примеры запросов `CURL` 
Больше информации [Тут](https://snipp.ru/php/curl) 
Пример с комментариями(Предполагается, что тип передачи данных json):

```php
$url = 'https://site.ru'; // Сайт куда отправляете
$id = '123';  // ID пользователя, которого меняете


// Собственно сам массив
$ArrayToSend = '{ "id": 123, 
    "title": "Help me!", 
    "group": "Users", 
    "state": "open", 
    "priority": "3 high", 
    "article": 
    { 
        "subject": "some subject of update", 
        "body": "some message of update" 

    }
}';


$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url . "/api/tickets/" . $id,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "PUT",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "$ArrayToSend",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/json",
        "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo $response;
}
```